# Use example.com/param instead of example.com/def_controller/index/param

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I need to acess my default contrillers index function without need to write a controllers name and index in the URL, but only pass the parameter value right after the domain name. Like in jsfiddle when after domain name you pass the identifier of fiddle.

How can i achive that in codeigniter site?

I guess it should be made in htaccess file.

Could somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to do with .htaccess. I don't think so.

You can customize all your URL in `routes.php` placed on `application/config`.

```
$route['(:num)'] = 'def_controller/index/$1';
```

[URI Routing Wildcards](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routes#wildcards)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{8})\$ /def_controller/index/$1
```

Comment: It takes me to localhost page